# PHP foreach change array value

Tags: php, foreach

When you have a foreach loop like below, I know that you can change the current element of the array through `$array[$key]`, but is there also a way to just change it through `$value`?

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

}
```

It's probably really simple, but I'm quite new to PHP so please don't be annoyed by my question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to directly assign values to `$value`, you want to reference `$value` by preceding it with `&` like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value){
    $value = 12321; //the same as $array[$key] = 12321;
}

unset($value);
```

After the `foreach` loop, you should do `unset($value)` because you're still able to access it after the loop.
**Note:** You can only pass `$value` by reference when the array is a variable. The following example won't work:

```
foreach(array(1, 2, 3) as $key => &$value){
    $value = 12321; //the same as $array[$key] = 12321
}

unset($value);
```

[The php manual on foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: In addition, we can simply use "foreach ($array as &$value)", without need for $key. I hope this helps you too. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

there's a function for that, and is builtin since early version of PHP, is called [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)